# How to create and sign a transaction locally using Go

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

Geth's code can be used as a library. Are there any code examples that use Geth to sign a transaction locally? I then want to POST the resulting string using `eth_sendRawTransaction`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Richard's answer pointed me in the right direction, but I had to remove some cruft to get it to do what I wanted. Here's some code that works (just replace the hardcoded values):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)

func main() {

    chainId := big.NewInt(3) // ropsten

    senderPrivKey, _ := crypto.HexToECDSA("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
    recipientAddr := common.HexToAddress("0xbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")

    nonce := uint64(7)
    amount := big.NewInt(1000000000000000000) // 1 ether
    gasLimit := big.NewInt(100000)
    gasPrice := big.NewInt(20000000000) // 20 gwei

    tx := types.NewTransaction(nonce, recipientAddr, amount, gasLimit, gasPrice, nil)

    signer := types.NewEIP155Signer(chainId)
    signedTx, _ := types.SignTx(tx, signer, senderPrivKey)
    fmt.Println(signedTx)

    var buff bytes.Buffer
    signedTx.EncodeRLP(&buff)
    fmt.Printf("0x%x\n", buff.Bytes())
}
```

Comment: Good work! :-) +1

Answer (score 3):

I've played around with this in the past, admittedly by borrowing code from elsewhere.

[Here](https://github.com/DaveAppleton/ether_go/blob/master/ethTxn/ethTxn.go)'s some code to get you started. The crux is below, though you'll need to check the linked file for the imports, etc.:

```
func SendEthereum(sender *ethKeys.AccountKey, 
                  recipient common.Address, 
                  amountToSend int64) (interface{}, error) {

    var zero interface{}

    myEipc, err := ethIpc.NewEthIpc()
    if err != nil {
        return zero, err
    }
    defer myEipc.Close()

    ec, _ := myEipc.EthClient()

    nonce, err := ec.PendingNonceAt(context.TODO(), sender.PublicKey())
    gasPrice, err := ec.SuggestGasPrice(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        return zero, err
    }

    fmt.Println("Nonce : ", nonce)
    fmt.Println("GasPrice : ", gasPrice)
    s := types.NewEIP155Signer(params.TestnetChainConfig.ChainId)

    var amount big.Int
    amount.SetInt64(amountToSend)

    var gasLimit big.Int
    gasLimit.SetInt64(121000) // because it is a send - quite standard

    data := common.FromHex("0x")
    t := types.NewTransaction(nonce, 
                              recipient, 
                              &amount, 
                              &gasLimit, 
                              gasPrice, 
                              data)

    nt, err := types.SignTx(t, s, sender.GetKey())
    if err != nil {
        return zero, err
    }

    err = ec.SendTransaction(context.TODO(), nt)

    return nt.Hash(), err
}
```

Comment: You will find that in https://github.com/DaveAppleton/ether_go/blob/master/ethTxn/ethTxn.go

Comment: Hi @DaveAppleton - thanks for pointing this out. When I originally stole it from your repo I think I'd put it into a Gist, then transferred it to a proper repo without remembering where it was from. I've updated the link in my answer to point to your  repo, but I'm happy to remove the whole answer if you'd prefer :-)

Comment: Not a problem :-)

That code is pretty old and I haven't really updated it. 

Have a look at my Gophercon India workshop slides also in my Github repo somewhere :

https://talks.godoc.org/github.com/DaveAppleton/Gophercon_in/.workshop.slide