# How create transaction raw data for using "eth_sendRawTransaction" in C#

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, ethereumjs-tx

My IoT device connects to another computer via Wi-Fi on which Ethereum (Truffle/Ganache) is running which receive a RPC from the IoT.
My task is to create raw transaction data on this IoT Device, so that I can use the *eth_sendRawTransaction* function (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendrawtransaction) via RPC. I have to create this raw transaction data in C# language.

But for creating this raw transaction data, I have to create ECDSA privat key, public key, derive address from public key, create the transaction (including: nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit, to, value, data), encode this data (RLP), hash the encoded data and last but nor least sign the hashed data with ECDSA private key. So in short --> [How to create and sign a transaction locally using Go](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17547/how-to-create-and-sign-a-transaction-locally-using-go), just in C# ^^

There are exist a library **ethereumjs-tx** or **web3** where I easy execute  but ethereumjs-tx is for JavaScript and web3 don't exist for C#. Is there a similar library for C#?

Or do I have to look at the exact function of the individual functions (in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum or rather https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx) and translate this manual in C#?

I found this https://goethereumbook.org/transaction-raw-create/ but everything is in GO.^^

Thanks a lot for your help/advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do what you need without building a raw transaction by yourself.

Take a look at [Nethereum](https://nethereum.com/) and the [Getting Started](https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/) page.

You can connect to a local node with something like
`var web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8545")`.
You would replace this with your node's IP and port.

And here is how to [send a transaction](https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nethereum-transferring-ether/#sending-a-transaction) using Nethereum, to the node that you previously connected (this would be your IoT device's node).

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer :)  

I found this: https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum
So I can just download it and integrate it as a library in my C# code?
That would make it much easier^^

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you found the answer useful consider marking it as the accepted answer :)