# How include Nethereum in an existing C# project as library

Tags: go-ethereum, nethereum

I try to include nethereum as a library in my C# project, so I have access to the appropriate functions (create transaction data, sign transaction data and so on...) for communicate to an arbitrary Ethereum Infura Node.
As a programming environment, I use an IDE which is very similar to Eclipse.
This is my intension: [How create transaction raw data for using "eth_sendRawTransaction" in C#](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71153/how-create-transaction-raw-data-for-using-eth-sendrawtransaction-in-c)
In short, a C# embedded device which try to comunicate with a GO# device (Infura Ethereum-Node)^^

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I found those somewhere in an old project, take look on them, i havn't used C# and dont know anything about it :) https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nethereum.Web3/ , https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nethereum.BlockchainProcessing/

Comment: Which IDE are you using exactly? Did you tried the [Getting Started guide](https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/), using the commands `dotnet add package Nethereum.Web3` and `dotnet restore`?

Comment: thanks for the answers.
but unfortunately that did not help :/
My IDE is Eclipse Mita.  
I read the https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/  but I dont understand why I need .Net SDK on my Computer?
I develop in Eclipse Mita and there I can include library's (for example mbedTLS), my source files and so on. I thought there is somehow a way to insert the library in my project environment and after this I flashed to my IoT embedded device.

Comment: The thing is that Nethereum is based on .Net, so you may not need it to get the library into your project, but you will need it to get the library working. Still, "it is compatible with all the operating systems (Windows, Linux, MacOS, Android and OSX)", as it says [here](https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#what-is-nethereum), so you could install .Net, install the library and use it in your project without problems.

Comment: Ok, I will try and then report if it worked :)

Comment: Hello,  
unfortunately I can't integrate a library. Is there an exact description of how the raw transaction data is generated or is there nothing left to do but look at the individual functions of go-ethereum and translate them gradually into C #?